# fullcalendar react add event with modal

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I don't know how to add event with modal.

I have the modal like function with form inside.

With this from the **handleDateSelect** function you can get the title for the event. But how you can get the data from the modal? Should i just send the request from the form?

```
let title = prompt("Please enter a new title for your event");
```

App.js

```
  render() {
    return (
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCreate={this.onCreate}
          onCancel={this.onCreate}
        />
        <FullCalendar
          select={this.handleDateSelect}
          events={getEventFromSource}
          eventAdd={this.handleEventAdd}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }


  handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
    let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;
    this.enableModal();

    let title = prompt("Please enter a new title for your event");
    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent(
        {
          // will render immediately. will call handleEventAdd
          title,
          start: selectInfo.startStr,
          end: selectInfo.endStr,
          allDay: selectInfo.allDay,
        },
        true
      ); // temporary=true, will get overwritten when reducer gives new events
    }
  };
```

Comment: Does you modal have a button that the user should click when they have entered all the data? You need to wait till the "Submit" button (or whatever you call it) is clicked, before you try to add the event to the calendar.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to call calendarApi.addEvent from the Modal component :(  thanks btw :)

Comment: You'd just have to make sure it's in scope (or at least that the main calendar object is in scope, so that you can request the API object from it (as per the instructions at the end of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react). Unfortunately I don't know enough about react to say exactly how you ought to achieve that, but that should be your goal. Either that or you expose a different method on your React calendar app which the modal can call, which in turn calls the fullCalendar API - that might help with encapsulation I guess. Again, I'm not a react user though so that's just my assumption.